# error with netlify cms deployment says Bundler v2 needed but bundler v2 was used

Tags: jekyll, bundler, netlify

When trying to deploy a jekyll site stored on github to netlify cms the build process throws this error

```
10:54:13 AM: Using ruby version 2.3.6
10:54:13 AM: Using PHP version 5.6
10:54:13 AM: Started restoring cached ruby gems
10:54:13 AM: Finished restoring cached ruby gems
10:54:13 AM: Installing gem bundle
10:54:13 AM: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
10:54:13 AM: Error during gem install
10:54:13 AM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
10:54:13 AM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
10:54:13 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
```

Note how it says bundler 2 or greater should be used.

In the GemFile.lock

at the end it shows....

```
BUNDLED WITH
2.0.1
```

Anyone any idea what is going on or how I can investigate/resolve this build error given that the site appears to meet the requirement already.

Or is it telling me that I need to configure the netlify build process to use Bundler 2? If so is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foiund the answer thanks to this blog.
https://stollerys.co.uk/2019/01/12/you-must-use-bundler-2-or-greater-with-this-lockfile

Netlify build servers don't use V2 of bundler so it barfs.

Had to downgrade my local version thus:

```
gem uninstall bundler
```

Then install netlify compatible version

```
gem install bundler -v 1.17.1
```

Delete the GemFile.lock

Regenerate it by running

```
bundle install
```

stage the files to git and then push them to github

```
git commit -am "Downgraded bundler for netlify compatibility"
git push
```

This triggered the netlify build and it worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `Gemfile.lock` from your repository since Netlify will use your `Gemfile` to build the snapshot for each build.

1. Add `Gemfile.lock` to `.gitignore`
2. Delete `Gemfile.lock`
3. Commit changes and push.

In the event that doesn't work, **undo those changes** and downgrade Bundler to `v1.17.2`

1. `gem uninstall bundler`
2. `gem install bundler --version '1.17.3'`
3. `bundle update`
4. commit changes and push.

Comment: Better to leave the lock file and just get a correct one up and running and when it changes force a build manually clearing the cache.